# Алгоритм создания пламени ракеты

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Здравствуйте!
Достаточно долго вожусь с 2D пламенем ракеты, а создать его достаточно реалистичным и рессурсозатратным так и не получилось. Стремлюсь к такому пламени:

[image]

Как у ракеты на этой картинке. 
Сразу хочу сказать, что нельзя пользоваться и подключать OpenGl и прочие библиотеки для работы с графикой. Все что есть - это метод установки пикселя такого-то цвета `r,g,b,a` в координаты `x,y( SetPixel(int x, int y, unsigned char r, ..g, ..b, ..a);)`, методы из `cmath.h`, ну и могу загружать в память картинки-спрайты, а потом попиксельно выводить их на экран.

Каков значит мой алгоритм:

1. опрелеляю позицию и направление дымка
2. пускаю дым изменяя масштаб картинки дымка и его прозрачность
   .. так последовательно кручу 5 дымков.... Ну то что у меня получилось никак не похоже на то, что изображено на картинке. А как создается дым, который изображен на картинке не могу понять. Кто может подсказать как сделать такое?

Comment: А может там просто художник кисточкой нарисовал, потом сфотографировали и выводят в фон этот .jpg?

Comment: Не, ну может там даже и так. Но мне хочется программно реализовать такое пламя.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такой огонь пишется с помощью [системы частиц](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86). Создаётся некоторое количество частиц (пикселей или спрайтов - небольших картинок), каждая из которых имеет свою скорость, направление, ускорение и т. п. На каждом шаге обновления сцены рассчитывается положение всех частиц, и они перерисовываются. Впрочем, судя по вашему вопросу, жто вам известно. Вот только вы на пару порядков промахнулись с числом частиц: для такого огня их должно быть несколько десятков или даже сотен. Каждая частица должна изменять не только своё положение, но и размер (чем дальше от сопла ракеты, тем уже струя пламени), возможно, цвет (для симуляции остывания струи пламени), и прозрачность. Стоит сделать эммитеры двух типов частиц: собственно пламя (спрайты с красным размытым пятном) и дым (серое пятно). Можно ещё отдельным эмиттером пристроить искры.

В общем, мне кажется, что вы идёте в верном направлении (хотя и искусственно ограничиваете себя отказом от использования графических библиотек, с помощью шейдеров можно было бы замутить гораздо более красивое пламя; чтобы не быть голословным, вот [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128286/) про симуляцию огня при помощи XNA, про шейдеты - во второй части). А с внешним видом пламени можно повозиться, подбирая различные параметры симуляции (размеры спрайтов, число частиц, скорость их движения, угасания и уменьшения).

Comment: А знаете как можно рассчитать наргузку на цп, выбрать оптимальное число частиц? Или это всё определяется опытным путем?

Comment: Честно говоря, не задумывался о таком. Вряд ли ест какие-то готовые формулы для расчёта нагрузки, тут многое зависит от реализации системы частиц. Скорее всего параметры подбираются чисто эмпирически (чтоб красиво выглядело), а затем реализацию подгоняют так, чтобы она вытягивала нужное число частиц.

Comment: Без добавления неких неоднородностей (каких именно, зависит от того, какие параметры моделируются)  "частиц" и м.б. моделирования их взаимодействия с турбулентностями среды, изображения такого, как на рисунке, пламени не добиться.